# Getting information from a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation which models the change of bacteria, $x(t)$ in relation to the immune response and carrying capacity. In what ways could I analyse this model? For example, I know I can calculate the steady states, but what other analytical techniques would you advise?

$$ B'(t) = \lambda B(t) - \frac{B(t)^2}{k} - \gamma \frac{P}{P+B(t)} B(t)$$

Comment: You could also do stability analysis on your steady state solutions

Comment: What would that show biologically?

Comment: Suppose we're at an equilibrium of $x_0$ bacteria, and suppose either some new bacteria enter or some bacteria suddenly die. How will the bacteria population change? Will they grow/decay back to $x_0$ or continue growing or decaying away from $x_0$? In general, in nature we generally find systems in their *stable* equilibria, not their unstable equilibria.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much! Would you be able to suggest any other forms of analysis that would enable me to acquire information from such ODE's (or even systems of ODE's)

Comment: You could sketch it using Euler's method for differential equations.

Comment: Would you be able to provide links regarding this? I'm sorry I have no knowledge of Euler's method

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method

Comment: I think you can solve this explicitly, though the algebra is messy. Write your ODE as $$u' = \frac{-u(u-z_{1})(u-z_{2})}{k(P+u)}$$ where $z_{1,2}$ are the roots of $u^{2} + u(P - \lambda k) + (\gamma k P - \lambda k P)$. Separate variables, use partial fractions and you end up with 

$$\frac{k P}{z_{1} z_{2}} \cdot \ln(u) + \frac{z_{1} + P}{z_{1}(z_{1} - z_{2})} \cdot \ln(u - z_{1}) - \frac{z_{2} + P}{z_{2}(z_{1} - z_{2})} \cdot \ln(u - z_{2}) = -t + C$$